# How to show that interaction potential depends only on separation of particles in system with position translation symmetry?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, symmetry, potential-energy, noethers-theorem, conservative-field

#### System

2 particles with mass moving in one spatial dimension $x$. Positions of particles are $x_1$ and $x_2$ respectively and they are only acted on by a conservative interaction force corresponding to potential energy $U(x_1,x_2)$

#### Question:

*Show that symmetry under spatial translations* $x\rightarrow x+a$ **requires** *the potential energy to only depend on the difference in positions $x_1 - x_2$*

#### Working/Thoughts:

Translation symmetry means that shifting both particles by the same amount along the axis doesn't affect the physics of the particles. Therefore, the particles will only have the same interaction potential energy after being shifted if it only depends on their relative separation - in one dimension this is the difference of their coordinates but if it was in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$ then it would be the norm of the difference of the position vectors. I think I understand the intuition behind this, but I don't know how to show it mathematically.

I have tried out different combinations such as: $x_1 + x_2$, $x_1-x_2$, $x_1x_2$, $(x_1)^2 - (x_2)^2$, $c_1x_1+c_2x_2$, $c(x_1-x_2)$, $(x_1-x_2)^2$ and I found only only combinations containing $(x_1-x_2)$ are invariant under $x_1\rightarrow x_1+a$ and $x_2\rightarrow x_2+a$. There is strong evidence for $U(x_1,x_2) = U(x_1-x_2)$ being the only way. However, I cannot be sure that the potential only depends on the difference in position.

My lecturer also showed me a solution that he didn't expect me to know using the method of characteristics that can be used to find this relation. I haven't learned that yet so I couldn't reproduce the same result.

**Question to you:** Is there a simpler way than the method of characteristics which one can use to show that $U(x_1,x_2) = U(x_1 - x_2)?$

Comment: A problem is a bad use of the same symbol $U$ to simultaneously indicate two different functions: $U=U(x,y)$ a function of **two** variables and $U=U(z)$ a function of **one** variable. Though this notation is physically clear, it is mathematically wrong... the kernel of the  problem  here regards math and not phys, so a better notation would help.

Comment: Yes I was confused how a function of two variables could become a function of one variable. Thanks for clarifying that they are different functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change variables to $$y_1 := (x_1+x_2)/2 \quad y_2 = (x_1-x_2)/2\tag{0}\:.$$

Notice that the map is smooth bijective with smooth inverse $x_1 = y_1+ y_2$ and $x_2 = y_1-y_2$ so that you can indifferently use coordinates $x$ or $y$.

Next, define $$V(y_1,y_2) := U(x_1(y_1,y_2), x_2(y_1,y_2))\:,$$
so that $$ U(x_1,x_2) = V(x_1+x_2, x_1-x_2)\:.\tag{1}$$

According to (0) and the very definition of $V$, saying that $$U(x_1+a,x_2+a) = U(x_1,x_2)$$ for every $a$ is the same as saying that
$$V(y_1,y_2) = V(y_1+a, y_2)$$
for every $a$.

In other words, $V(y_1',y_2) = V(y_1,y_2)$ for every $y_1,y'_1$ and $y_2$.

In other words, *$V$ is constant in the first entry*:

$$V(y_1,y_2)= W(y_2)\:,$$
for some function $W$ of a single variable.

Inserting this result in (1), we have

$$U(x_1,x_2)= W(x_1-x_2)$$
for some function $W$ with a unique entry.

Comment: This is great Mr Moretti. I just wanted to clarify a couple of things. Is the statement  $ U(x_1 + a, x_2 + a) = U(x_1,x_2) \implies V(y_1,y_2) = V(y_1+a,y_2)$, because when $x_1 \rightarrow x_1 + a$ and $x_2 \rightarrow x_2 + a$, the variables $y_1 \rightarrow y_1 + a$ and $y_2 \rightarrow y_2$ because of how they are defined? Also is $V(y_1,y_2)=V(y_1+a,y_2)$ because you imposed translation symmetry here? Finally can we say $V(y_1,y_2)=W(y_2)$ because $y_1$ is constant and so it can be included in the function itself rather than as an input parameter?

Comment: Yes to all questions.

Answer (score 1):

For $4$ points $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$, there exists $a$ such that $x_1 = a + y_1$ and $x_2 = a + y_2$ if, and only if $x_1 - x_2 = y_1 - y_2$.

This, means that if $x_1 - x_2 = y_1 - y_2$, then we must have $ U(x_1,x_2) = U(y_1, y_2)$.

Now, if we try to define a function $\tilde{U}$ of $1$ variable such that $U(x_1,x_2) = \tilde{U}(x_1 - x_2)$, the only way this can fail is if their are points $x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2$ with $x_1 - x_2 = y_1 - y_2$ and $U(x_1,x_2) \not= U(y_1,y_2)$. But, as we have seen, this cannot be true if the system is invariant by translation.

Another, maybe simpler, way to see this : let $\tilde U(x) = U(x,0)$. Then, by translation invariance :$$U(x,y) = U(x-y,y-y) = U(x-y,0) = \tilde U(x-y)$$

Comment: Checking I have got this right: the first statement is of translation symmetry, so shifting the system by $a$ doesn't change the separation of the positions. The second point is that the potential can't depend on the position but only on the difference in positions, because of this translation symmetry and the third point is that the only way the function for potential can't be written as a function with one input  $x_1 - x_2$ is if the potential before shifting system $\neq$ potential after shifting, which would contradict the translation symmetry so the potential is a function of separation

Comment: The first statement is just a statement of the fact that the space we are considering is a vector space (in a way, it is the statement of translation symmetry of the underlying space). The second statement is the actual translational symmetry of the system.